# How can I specify encoding when parsing text with Apache TIKA?

Tags: java, parsing, apache-tika

The question is pretty self-explanatory.

The problem I am facing is that any Tika example code I found online is using a StringWriter, as shown below. If i could somehow make this use an OutputStreamWriter, I can specify the encoding no problem... Any help would be appreciated.

```
InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(pathname);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
SAXTransformerFactory factory = (SAXTransformerFactory)SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();
TransformerHandler handler = factory.newTransformerHandler();
handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD,"html");
handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT,"no");
handler.setResult(new StreamResult(sw));
parser.parse(inStream, handler, metadata, context);
```

Comment: Can you just set the encoding when you turn the String from the StringWriter into something that gets written out?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? The problem is that after this point I have to do a bunch of stuff to the string and so I was basically doing sw.toString() and using that result to manipulate it. but that loses encoding...

Comment: Strings in Java are always Unicode. You only need to worry about encodings when reading in bytes/files/streams and turning that into a String, and when writing a string back out again. So, something like `new FileOutputStream("test.txt").write("Test".getBytes("iso-8859-1"));` should be fine for outputting your string in a set encoding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the encoding by the metadata object.
I've used this snippet:

```
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;

Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
metadata.add(Metadata.CONTENT_ENCODING, DATAFILE_CHARSET);
String parsedString = tika.parseToString(inputStream, metadata);
```

By default tika tries to determine the encoding itself, when parsing html.
But sometimes this could lead to errors.

Comment: Details see org.apache.tika.parser.html.HtmlParser.getEncoding()

Comment: unfornatly tika takes this as a proposal, so I encountered files where tika uses another (false) encoding, but in most cases this helped.

Answer (score -3):

if you parse text , you can use traditional IO to specify encoding .

Comment: Could you please expand on this answer to make it more useful.